# ActiveMQ doesn't recognize Stomp: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [stomp+ssl]

Tags: activemq-classic, puppet, stomp, ubuntu-16.04, mcollective

I'm trying to set up mcollective/activemq on a puppetmaster (open source puppet).  I am having a problem where ActiveMQ does not recognize the Stomp protocol.  Here is the relevant snippet in my `/etc/activemq/instances-enabled/activemq/activemq.xml` file that should enable stomp+ssl:

```
<transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp+ssl" uri="stomp+ssl://0.0.0.0:61614?needClientAuth=true&amp;transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

When I start ActiveMQ via `service activemq start`, I notice that the daemon doesn't end up running (I don't see it as a process).  Then I tried running `service activemq console activemq`, and it looks like the problem is that it can't find the stomp Transport scheme.   Here is the first error that I see in the output (and the error persists throughout the output):

> ERROR | Failed to start Apache
>   ActiveMQ ([localhost,
>   ID:my-servers-hostname.example.com-40447-1475514312306-0:1], java.io.IOException: Transport
>   Connector could not be registered in
>   JMX: java.io.IOException: Transport
>   scheme NOT recognized: [stomp+ssl])

ActiveMQ recognizes openwire just fine. When using openwire+ssl only, without using stomp+ssl, the ActiveMQ daemon starts fine with no errors.  However, when I try running `mco find`, I get an error because it seems that mco is still trying to use stomp+ssl (and ActiveMQ only has openwire+ssl enabled):

> error 2016/10/03 17:26:59: activemq.rb:149:in `on_ssl_connectfail' SSL session creation with stomp+ssl://mcollective@localhost:61614 failed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 61614

Perhaps I need to adjust my mco config to use openwire instead of stomp?  I wasn't sure where or what file that configuration would be in.  Not sure why it doesn't recognize stomp, but I was wondering what my options are here.  Is it even possible to use MCollective/ActiveMQ using only openwire+ssl, or is using stomp a requirement if I want to use mco?  I don't think this is a port issue, as the relevant ports are open on the server I believe.

Here are the relevant packages/versions installed on my machine:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial)
puppet: 4.7.0
ActiveMQ: 5.13.2
ruby-stomp: 1.3.5-1
MCollective (mco) version: 2.9.0
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

I've run into the same problem with the embedded ActiveMQ server in my project. Turns out I needed to add the following dependencies to my pom.

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
>         <version>5.15.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
>         <version>5.15.0</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

In your case, I think you need to get hold of those 2 jars and add them to your ActiveMQ installation.

Answer (score 1):

In `activemq` package provided by ubuntu 16+ library stomp transport was not included. I do not know why.
Yoy can download it manually and place in `/usr/share/activemq/lib`:

```
cd /usr/share/activemq/lib
# check your actviemq version before (apt-cache policy activemq) and use the relevant version of library.
wget https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/activemq/activemq-stomp/5.13.5/activemq-stomp-5.13.5.jar
service activemq restart
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include details as to why that code will answer the question

Comment: @CalvT븃 added more info

Comment: This fixes the problem for ActiveMQ on Ubuntu 16.04 where ActiveMQ just won't start when invoked via `systemctl start activemq.service`; for example when trying to run a classic (Puppet 3.x) MCollective broker with ActiveMQ (as managed by [voxpupuli/mcollective](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-mcollective) instead of the new [Choria MCollective deployment](https://choria.io/) which uses NATS as middleware. Running `/etc/init.d/activemq console mcollective` helps identifying the problem of the missing Stomp library, which is not logged anywhere else.